# Sojourn time for M/M/c tandem queue

Tags: queueing-theory

In Chapter 9 of the book Handbook of Healthcare System Scheduling, they present the M/M/1 tandem queue with the following diagram:

[image: Tandem queue]

And they also mention that **the mean sojourn time of the entire system is the sum of the mean sojourn times of Queue 1 and Queue 2**. Since Queue 1 and Queue 2 have 1 server each (they are M/M/1 stations), I was wondering if the same property holds **when Queue 1 and/or Queue 2 have multiple servers**.

Comment: This is known as a Jackson network. The property in question holds when there are multiple servers at a station, so long as the system is stable.

Comment: @Math1000 thanks! Do you have any book/reference that I can cite?